# How to order xml with item fields in scrapy?

Tags: python, xml, serialization, scrapy

I have a spider written that will scrape a webpage and populate the fields in an item. The item has fields as follows

```
class exampleitem():
    ex1 = Field()
    ex2 = Field()
    ex3 = Field()
    ... and so forth
```

When I scrape and export into an xml file, the order of the Fields become messed up and returns something like this

```
<items>
    <item>
        <ex2> <value> xyz </value> </ex2>
        <ex3> <value> abc </value> </ex3>
        <ex1> <value> ghi </value> </ex1>
    </item>
    ... so forth
</items>
```

I want to make it so that the xml is formatted in the exact order it is written in the Fields() for my item.py file.

I've been doing research for the past hour or so, and I know it has something to do with my pipeline and utilizing xmlitemexporter, but I have no idea at all how to custom make my pipeline or even where to start.

In short, I am getting lost in the jargon and I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in a direction or give me a short example code of how I can begin to format my scraped items!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[scrapy Items](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py) are wrappers of python dict and will return the item fields in an unpredicted order

```
def keys(self):
    return self._values.keys()
```

to change that you can either override this function in your items like:

```
class exampleitem(Item):
    ex1 = Field()
    ex2 = Field()
    ex3 = Field()

    def keys(self):
        return ['ext1', 'ext2', 'ext3']
```

or, in a more generic way to implement [DictItem](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py) and use python's [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) instead of the python's default dict that its currently using.

Comment: you should change your name from @Guy to God. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had no idea this existed...

Comment: I tried to use this method to order my CSV export fields, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: did not work in what way? use the link to see DictItem code, see the line `fields={}`, a regular python dict that when asked for its keys it returns them in an arbitrary order, in the answer I suggested to force the order of the field that `keys(self)` function return, if course you'll have to change those fields with the names of the field from your item class, I hope it helps.

Comment: same thing happened to me, i made the changes to my items.py file but still the order is not determined by what i did there.